# My web page does not collect any data. Should I disclose my hosting company (which may log requests) in my privacy policy?

Tags: web-hosting, github, privacy-policy, gdpr

I have a static blog hosted on GitHub. I do not collect any data about anyone. GitHub pretty straightforward states that they do collect some data in their [GitHub Privacy Statement](https://help.github.com/articles/github-privacy-statement/). So if a user go to my web page he is indeed tracked, but not by me but by my hosting company.

By "tracked" I mean (stolen from [here](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2012/apr/23/cookies-and-web-tracking-intro)):

> Server logs: when you load a page on a website, you are making a request to that website's server. This server will log the type of request that was made and will store information such as: IP address (which will allow website owners to infer location), the date and time the browser loaded the page, what page was loaded, and what site or page the browser was on before it came to that page (referrer).

Should I disclose my hosting company privacy policy and link to it from my privacy policy?

(but cmon, every web page is hosted SOMEWHERE, should every web page link to its hosting company privacy policy?)

Comment: That's the privacy policy for github.com. Are you sure Github is tracking users using Github _pages_ (which is what I assume you're using)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but GitHub does states that it does track (see the link I gave).

Answer (score 1):

Topical at this point in time - but boring too.

This is a jurisdictional legal question. It needs legal advice for technical correctness.

I'd be very surprised if any jurisdiction classifies anonymous visitor data (i.e. logs) as personal/protected/private data.

But if you're worried, you can seek legal advice. A small disclaimer on the bottom of your site might help cover your backside - something like "This site is hosted on github - you can review their privacy policy here".

Morally, I don't think there is any obligation because I don't think any sane human would regard anonymous logs as "their data" deserving of protection.

Just my view.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the collected data, simply disclose it in your Privacy Policy.

[Ecquire](http://ecquire.com/blog/privacy-policy/) has an example of Privacy Policy for "no collection of data", but keep in mind that you should disclose if third parties (Google Analytics, etc.) collect data for you even if you don't directly.

[image]

Comment: I would also mention including a link to the privacy policy of any 3rd party including Google for analytics. Otherwise, this is something close to my original privacy policy and right up my alley! I can appreciate the humor! Cheers!!

Comment: This does not answer the question. I asked about 3rd party privacy policies. Because if you say you do not store data, then you dont say whole the truth because your hosting company does it for you.

Comment: Please do not post images. Use text.